# Eclipse IDE: incorrect errors after loading a JSP page in a javascript editor

Tags: eclipse, aptana

I just installed an Aptana plugin, and made the mistake of opening my .jsp page in a Javascript Source Editor.  It generated hundreds of errors that now won't go away.  How do I get rid of the errors?

They are dumb errors like "missing a semicolon" on HTML syntax lines.  I've tried reopening the JSP in a JSP editor, but the errors still won't go away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few steps you can do...

The first, and the easiest, try is to clean your workspace. From the application menu, do a `Project | Clean` and select `Clean All`

If that didn't help, you might need to manually delete the error markers for that project. Go to your workspace location and get into `/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.projects/<project name>/`. There should be a `.markers` file in there. Delete it, restart eclipse from a command line with a `-clean`, do a `Clean All` as mentioned above.

Cheers